# Combinatorics question - why am I over counting?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

A group of 12 people want to go to a concert. They can travel in a small car that takes one driver and one passenger and two cars each taking one driver and 4 passengers. If there are five drivers in the group, in how many different ways can they travel.

**What I did:** There are 5C3 ways I can choose the drivers and then 3 ways that I can arrange them into the cars (i.e. I'm deciding who drives the small car and the rest is forced).

There are then 9 ways I can choose who the passenger is in the small car and then 8C4 ways to divide the remaining passengers into 2 groups of 4. This yields and answer of 18900 ways and yet the given answer is 6300 ways. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is ambiguous--what counts as a "different way to travel"?  Are the two large cars distinguishable?  Does it matter only who is in each car, or does it also matter who is driving them?

Comment: Possibly I’m not yet awake, but I see nothing wrong with your solution, unless the two large cars are distinguishable, and in that case you’d be undercounting by a factor of $2$, not overcounting.

Comment: Thanks both - so there's no way the answer could be 6300, as given in the solutions?

Comment: Your answer is right. There is no way it can be $6300$. I think the book solution may have made an error in not distinguishing between drivers as to who drives and who sit as passengers from them.

Comment: Maybe the questions intends to only count which people are traveling together without regard for who is driving, as Eric suggested above. Partition the $12$ people into $2,5,5$ arbitrarily and use inclusion-exclusion to subtract the cases with at least one driverless car. Too complicated for me 

Comment: Ah that makes sense @MathLover. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm new to this) but I think the correct answer is 6300:

12 total people

You have 5 drivers and 3 cars (5C3) you take 3 people, so you're left with 9 people

One of the cars supports one passenger (9C1) you take 1 person, now 8 people are left

The other car supports 4 passengers (8C4) so you're left with 4 people that automatically go into the other car that supports 4 passengers

So (5C3) * (9C1) * (8C4)=6300

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).